# Sintaxis correcta al usar inner join con paginación en Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Tengo la siguiente query:

```
select * from 
  (select rownum rnum, p.* from 
    (select DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
     DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
     DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID,
     EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
     EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, 
     EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, 
     EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID,
     EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
     EMPLOYEES.DETAILS 
     from HR.EMPLOYEES 
     INNER JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS on
     HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID=EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID 
   where EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID >= 1) p 
 where rownum <= 4) 
where rnum >= 2
```

que me arroja el siguiente error:

> Error SQL: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
>   00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

Si los campos tienen diferentes nombres, no hay error. Como ejemplo, esta query es correcta:

```
select * from 
  (select rownum rnum, p.* from 
    (select DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
     DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
     DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID,
     EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
     EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, 
     EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, 
     EMPLOYEES.DETAILS 
     from HR.EMPLOYEES 
     INNER JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS on
     HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID=EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID 
     where EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID >= 1) p 
  where rownum <= 4) 
where rnum >= 2
```

¿Cuál es la sintaxis corecta para hacer un inner join con paginación, y campos de diferentes tablas con los mismos nombres? ¿qué debo hacer para evitar el error ORA-00918 en mi primera query?

Estoy usando Oracle 11g.

Comment: has probado ponerle alias a las columnas que tienen igual nombre en ambas tablas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu consulta tiene dos veces la columna `DEPARTMENT_ID` y dos veces la columna `MANAGER_ID`. Esto no puede ocurrir en una *tabla derivada*.

```
select *
  from (select rownum rnum, p.*
          from (select   DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
                       , DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME
                       , DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID
                       , EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID
                       , EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME
                       , EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME
                       , EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID Manager_ID_Duplicado
                       , EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID as Department_ID_Duplicado
                       , EMPLOYEES.DETAILS 
                  from HR.EMPLOYEES
                       INNER JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS on HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID=EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
                 where EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID >= 1
               ) p 
         where rownum <= 4
       ) 
 where rnum >= 2
```

Le he puesto un alias a la segunda vez que aparece dicha columna. No tengo oracle a mano para probar, pero con esto debiera funcionar.

La ambigüedad reportada por oracle no tiene que ver con que las columnas no estén calificadas, sino con el hecho de que este query constituye una especie de *vista al vuelo* y cada columna debe tener un nombre único, de otra forma, al referenciarse en el query más externo, el motor no podría resolver a cual de las columnas se hace referencia.

## Hablando de Paginación

No tienes por qué hacer dos *tablas derivadas* una dentro de la otra para construir una *paginación* en oracle. Si tienes una versión moderna del motor, puedes valerte de las cláusulas [`offset` y `fetch next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html) para hacerlo de manera más elegante, sencilla y óptima.

En tu caso podría quedar algo como:

```
select   DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
       , DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME
       , DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID
       , EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID
       , EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME
       , EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME
       , EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID Manager_ID_Duplicado
       , EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID as Department_ID_Duplicado
       , EMPLOYEES.DETAILS
  from HR.EMPLOYEES
       INNER JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS on HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID=EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
 where EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID >= 1
 order by EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID
offset 1 rows
 fetch next 3 rows only
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! No puedo usar fetch y offset porque éstos están disponibles desde la versión 12c, y mi query es para la versión 11g (¡díganme si me equivoco!). En internet encontré tutoriales sobre paginación, y otros sobre inner join, pero no para las dos cosas juntas.